# Understanding an FFmpeg command (blurring a video)

Tags: ffmpeg

I searched for a FFmpeg command to blur part of a video, and found the following:

```
ffmpeg -i short.mp4 -filter_complex 
       "[0:v]split=2[v0][v1]; 
        [v0]crop=200:200:60:30,boxblur=10[fg]; 
        [v1][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" -map "[v]" 
    -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart filtered.mp4
```

([cut-cat minimal video editing bash script](http://www.hildstrom.com/projects/cut-cat/ffmpeg_notes.txt))

Unfortunately, I can't blur the part of the video that I want to blur. So, I took a picture with the same resolution and color so that someone may help me understand what to do, and perhaps even explain what the numbers in the code above mean or refer to.

Here's the picture:

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/4fZNcgN/ask-368-X320-WHITE-BLURED.png

Comment: Welcome! Please share your answer so that others may benefit. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The above command line was copied from [FFmpeg - Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/a/901705) which also provides a good explanation:

> Note: The x and y offset numbers in overlay (60 and 30 in this
>   example) must match the crop offsets.
>
> What this example does:
>
> - Crop the copy to be the size of the area to be blurred. In this example: a 200x200 pixel box that is 60 pixels to the right (x axis)
>     and 30 pixels down (y axis) from the top left corner.
> - Blur the cropped area.
> - Overlay the blurred area using the same x and y parameters from the crop filter.

So: the `200:200` is the size of the blurred area and `60:30` its position relative to the top-left corner. The input `v` is split into two streams `v0` and `v1` where `v0` is blurred and the result is named `fg`. Streams `v1` and `fg` are composed to the final stream `v`.